# Is there a way to export and successively restore into another project DialogFlowCX an agent without losing environments and Flow-parts?

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-api, dialogflow-cx

Since a few days I'm working with GCP services, more specifically with DialogFlowCX.
Currently for a project I'm trying to **Export** some DF agents and **Import** them back into other projects.

Using the REST API at:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/export

and here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/restore

I've succeded at exporting my old agent and importing it into a new one.

The problem is that, by some test I've conducted:

1. Without specifying the *environment* body-param in the import-request the new agent is complete of every flows and exactly the same as the exported-one but will not have any environment existing after the restore.(so i will lose some data regarding them - I need it)
2. by specifying the environment-name in the *environment* body-param it will save just that environment losing part of the Default-Start-Flow flow. Also if that flow existing and complete in the specified env. [example below]

This image illustrates the second case described.
[image]

Is there a way to merge more export into one or to properly export/restore the complete agent that exists in the first project?

Comment: The first behaviour is as intended  i.e. the environment will not be created after restore. The second issue that you are facing needs further investigation, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).  Also, consider mentioning the exact steps you followed to create the agent in the case/issue.

Comment: Done that. I'm waiting for responses now. Issues at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204328114

Comment: Has there been any update on this?  I'm running into a similar problem.  My team requires the export to contain, at a minimum, flow versions, and it appears that they cannot be reconstructed using the @google-cloud/dialogflowcx library.  

I'm also not able to see the issue tracker information- it requires access to be granted.

Comment: Hi binarygiant. It has not been solved yet, and the ticket has been closed. To not face it again I suggest you to include everything inside a flow so it wont be cutted. In my case the cutted parts were in the default flow.
Use also versioning and environments for export and restore by environments.